# css style sheet from content page

Tags: css, master-pages

Iv'e got a content page with a link to a style sheet which I want to be specific for that page , i.e. I want the design to be specific for that page when it loads and takes its place in the contentplaceholder on the main page.

IN MY CONTENT PAGE :

```
  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">  
      <link href="~/Styles/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </asp:Content>
```

IN MY MAIN PAGE :

```
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">       
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

MY STYLE SHEET ~/Styles/StyleSheet1.css  just for example I'll give this id to some table in my content page.

```
       #defualt_tbl
       {
          background-color:Gray;
       }

       <table id="defualt_tbl">
```

The table does not become gray , when I click viewsource in the master page the link is present in the head section.

```
        <link href="~/Styles/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Did you look at the generated source? I mean, if your table has something like runat="server", that ID may be something completely else than you expect....check that first.

Comment: is this all thats in the stylesheet?

Comment: no thats not all..
that was an  example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it !

but i belive your answers work as well .

```
  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
     <link href='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Styles/StyleSheet1.css") %>' rel="stylesheet"    type="text/css" />
  </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the `~` root specifier in server controls, the browser doesn't understand that URL, and doesn't know where your application root is either even if it would.

Put `runat="server"` in the `link` tag, or use an URL that is relative to the site root:

```
<link href="/Styles/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can use the tilda ~ for the path in the link.  I think the tilda(~) is a .net shortcut, and since your just rendering html the browser won;t know where to look.