# CSS style sheet in child content place holder not being applied

Tags: css, asp.net, master-pages, stylesheet, contentplaceholder

I have a master page with CSS style sheet references in its head tag. I also have a Content Place Holder in the master page head tag. In a child page using that master page I've placed a CSS style sheet reference specific to that page in the Content Place Holder of the head.

The CSS style sheet in the child page has styles which are supposed to override some of the styles in the CSS style sheets in the master page. Only some of the styles from the master page are supposed to be overridden not all.

The CSS style sheet references in the master page are at the top of the head tag and the Content Place Holder is at the bottom so I thought the one in the child page would take precedence but it doesn't.

How can I get the style sheet in the child page to get precedence over the style sheets in the master page?

Can someone explain what causes this to happen?

Comment: It might be some asp.net render way to render things. Do you have a specific container with a class where you want it to style on the child page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431694/css-style-sheet-from-content-page?rq=1).

My style sheet reference looked like this

```
 <link href="~/Styles/PopForms.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and as explained [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431694/css-style-sheet-from-content-page?rq=1) the `~` is not understood by the browser in this context.

I changed the reference to

```
<link href="../Styles/PopForms.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and it now works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same class name in two different pages and you want to change the default, just use '!important' immediately after the declaration.

```
.red-background { background-color: red; } /* MASTER */
.red-background { background-color: green !important; } /* CHILD PAGE */
```

Comment: 1. I've read that using !important is not good practice.  2. I'm using style sheet references for style sheets being used on other pages also, where I don't wont to use !important. 3. Is it possible to use !important for a style sheet reference?

Comment: 1. What awesome in programming that there are so many solutions for every single question/bag/problem.
You can check via JS the page name and decide what styles to remove, but it is the long way.

2. your code won't work by changing the location of the css in this case.
3. i'm using !important and for me it is very best solution for a lot of situation. it is declared for these kind of cases.

Comment: you can try to create a container class in the child page - call it 'child-container' for example, and in the css do derive to the container like - >
.child-container > .red-background { background-color: green; }

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `!important` going with a child page container/target with a specific class is the way to go

```
.some-class { 
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.child-container .some-class {
  background-color: deeppink;
}
```

Comment: In the html mark up of the child page would I have to give each tag this class or would it be enough to give it to the div containing all of the page?

Comment: @DovMiller container that keeps the whole page. Good you sorted it out.

Comment: Thank you! In any event you've been helpful!